# Qt XSLT for-each-group not recognised

Tags: qt, qtxml

The [Qt Documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/xmlprocessing.html) states that for-each-group is supported when using QXmlQuery.  However I get an error when I try and use it:

"The element with local name for-each-group does not exist in XSL-T."

Am I missing something?

I am using Qt 4.8.4.
I am calling QXmlQuery like this:

```
QXmlQuery xmlQuery(QXmlQuery::XSLT20);
xmlQuery.setMessageHandler(&messageHandler);
xmlQuery.setFocus(&xmlBuffer);
xmlQuery.setQuery(&queryFile);
```

The line from my XSL file looks like this:

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="../readings/slot" group-by="@slot_dtm">
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As of Qt 5.12, this issue is still present. It seems that Qt simply does not support `xsl:for-each-group`. That was also the result of a 2013 [blog post](http://xilexio.org/?p=94) where somebody analyzed this issue.

There are some limited ways to achieve the same functionality without `xsl:for-each-group`, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38087046). But this did not work for me due to a bug in Qt's XSLT variable binding. Finally I resorted to avoid even a `xsl:for-each` loop because the order and identity of the groups was known initially. See [my code](https://github.com/fairdirect/foodrescue-app/blob/942bcf4ce5a11a873192c04b876ec1821e4c48f0/src/docbook-to-qthtml.xsl#L80).

**tl;dr:** Unfortunately Qt XSLT is barely useful as of Qt 5.12; like they say, the implementation is "experimental". And it seems there was very little work done on it since 2013.