# How to do a for-each-group in XSLT 1.0 without keys/Muenchian grouping

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am currently working with XSLT and trying to group nodes by a sub-string of an attribute. The only thing is I'm working in an environment where I can't use an xsl:key. I was wondering the best way to go about grouping something such as:

`<RESULTS>
    <RESULT ID="Result:1-1" Value="32" /> 
    <RESULT ID="Result:1-2" Value="3225" /> 
    <RESULT ID="Result:1-3" Value="372" />
    <RESULT ID="Result:1-4" Value="64732" /> 
    <RESULT ID="Test:2-1" Value="6362" /> 
    <RESULT ID="Test:2-2" Value="352" />
    <RESULT ID="Test:2-3" Value="325" />
    <RESULT ID="Result:3-1" Value="3243" />
    <RESULT ID="Result:3-2" Value="2332" />
    <RESULT ID="Result:3-3" Value="342" />
    <RESULT ID="Result:3-4" Value="2134" /> 
</RESULTS>`

So that it could be formatted where there is a table that groups the Results by the last digit in the ID and displays their values. For example, it would group Result:1-1, Test:2-1, and Result:3-1 in the first table and list their values below it.

Some sort of expected result would be:

```
| Table 1 |
|---------|
| 32      |
| 6362    |
| 3243    |

| Table 2 |
|---------|
| 3225    |
| 352     |
| 2332    |

| Table 3 |
|---------|
| 372     |
| 325     |
| 342     |

| Table 4 |
|---------|
| 64732   |
| 2134    |
```

Any suggestions as to certain methods of grouping to use or certain fuctions would be much appreciated!
Thanks for reading and any help you have to offer!

Comment: "*The only thing is I'm working in an environment where I can't use an xsl:key.*" What is this environment? `xsl:key` is an integral part of the XSLT language. If you cannot use it, you're not using XSLT - and how are we supposed to know what else doesn't work in your environment?

Comment: It's a very specific environment that I have set up that reads parts of XSLT to transform information by inserting it into templates. A key would require that it be outside of the scope of the template, but I can't have that. I didn't realize you had to use every predefined element in a language to qualify as using it, sorry.

Comment: "*I didn't realize you had to use every predefined element in a language to qualify as using it*" https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#conformance

Comment: I understand that you think the processor should be able to handle `xsl:key`; however, even if it can't the other logic is still in line with how XSLT works so I feel like I am using XSLT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The alternative to Muenchian grouping is described in the same [article](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html) that explains it; it is also labeled there as "very inefficient".

The following stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/RESULTS">
    <html>
        <xsl:for-each select="RESULT">
            <xsl:variable name="key" select="substring(@ID, string-length(@ID))" />
            <xsl:if test="not(preceding-sibling::RESULT[substring(@ID, string-length(@ID))=$key])">
                <table border="1">
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            <xsl:text>Table </xsl:text>
                            <xsl:value-of select="$key"/>
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:for-each select="../RESULT[substring(@ID, string-length(@ID))=$key]">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="@Value"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </table>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when applied to your example input, will return (rendered):

[image]

Note that this is different from the result you have posted - but I believe it is correct nevertheless.

Comment: Thanks, yea I messed up my "results" a little, I'll edit that now to fix it. I know it's inefficient but I plan on making it work for now!